# "Fundamental Theorem" $\int_a^bF'(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$ when $F$ is not everywhere differentiable

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

When $F$ is not everywhere differentiable but almost everywhere differentiable, can we still write:

$\int_a^bF'(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)?$

In my opinion there is no problem since $F'(x)$ does not exist for only a measure zero set, which cannot affect the result of integration. To formalize this, do we need to use Lebesgue integration?

Comment: Look at [absolute continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity). Indeed, we need Lebesgue integration to formalize it.

Comment: @Surb From this wiki page, we could use Lebesgue integral to formalize this?

Comment: You can't formalize it without Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
F(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if} & x\in [-1,0], \\
1 & \text{if} & x\in (0,1], \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $F$ is differentiable everywhere but $x=0$, and $F'(x)=0$, $F'$ is a measurable function, which is Lebesgue integrable and
$$
\int_{-1}^1 F'(x)\,dx=0\ne F(1)-F(-1)=1.
$$

However, if $F$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), then $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $\int_a^b F'\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$.

Answer (score 4):

Look at  [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) : it is continuous over $[0,1]$, diffeentiable almost everywhere, but one has $$\int_0^1 F'(x) dx = 0 \neq 1 = F(1)-F(0)$$